# Link binaries with Library in Xcode 4 for Soundcloud wrapper

Tags: iphone, xcode4, soundcloud, ios-frameworks

When I attempt step 3 in the XCode part of the [setup section of these instructions](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Setup.md) I can see Soundcloud.API framework as an option to add, but not libSoundCloud.a or libOAuth2Client.a. Any ideas? I'm using Xcode 4 and the iPhoneTestApp as my base project. I then added the Soundcloud project to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you added the Project and did all steps mentioned in the guide, you got to Project, then select the target, go to Build Phases and select "Link Binary with ...". The screen should look like the one below. If you select the `.a` file it will be linked statically, if you select the framework it will be linked dynamically.

The project is a plain iPhone project with no more code added.

[image: Screen]

Comment: This is my problem. I can see the SoundCloudAPI.framework on the right of your screenshot, but not the others. I didn't access the files through Github, but downloaded them to my Desktop. I think it may have some files missing which I'm looking into right now.

Comment: I think the issue then may be in the git submodules mentioned in the README, I would strongly advise to download the files using git.